# Using "string.byte" on a UTF-8 character returns an array, how can I convert that array back to the UTF-8 character?

Tags: utf-8, lua

Let me explain my issue with an example:

```
local Character = utf8.char(1114111) --Example UTF8 character
local A,B,C,D = Character:byte(1, -1)
print(A,B,C,D) -- 244 143 191 191
```

How can I convert "244 143 191 191" back to "1114111"?

Comment: `utf8.codepoint(string.char(table.unpack{A, B, C, D}))`

Comment: Thank you so much, it works just as I want it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `utf8.codepoint` function takes a byte array as a string and converts it into a sequence of codepoints, with each return value being a separate codepoint. So you just have to convert those four values into a string for use by `utf8.codepoint`. `string.char(A, B, C, D)` would do it adequately.